# How to invoke a play application without hitting the URL in play 2.4.2

Tags: playframework

I'm using Play Framework (version 2.4.2) with WebsphereMQ. So I would like to invoke my Play application without hitting the execution URL (http://localhost:9000) on server startup.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the behavior of [development mode](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayConsole#Running-the-server-in-development-mode), which should not be used in production. From the docs:

> In this mode, the server will be launched with the auto-reload feature enabled, meaning that for each request Play will check your project and recompile required sources. If needed the application will restart automatically.

In [production mode](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Production) the app starts immediately, without requiring a request. [From the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying):

> We have seen how to run a Play application in development mode, however the `run` command should not be used to run an application in production mode. When using `run`, on each request, Play checks with sbt to see if any files have changed, and this may have significant performance impacts on your application.
>
> There are several ways to deploy a Play application in production mode. Let’s start by using the recommended way, creating a distribution artifact.